# MS Access: How do I access protected VBA code and bypass "Unexpected error 40230"?

Tags: vba, ms-access, vbe

My forerunner built a AccessDB consisting of .accdb & .accde file. The DB (.accdb file) is stored in our network drive and each user has to copy the frontend file (.accde) to access and work with the DB. The Database is not password-protected.
Embedded VBA codes are used to generate the report and there have been some bugs and errors. So I have to take care of them. The VBA code is password-protected and of course he left without revealing it to anyone.

Now, each time when I try to open the VBE (Alt+F11 or through the  menu "DATABASE TOOLS"-"Visual Basic"), I will get the warning "Unexpected error 40230" (serveral times, one for each form and report). Clicking through the warnings, I can open the VBE, but I cannot see the code.

I have already tried to open the properties of my project in the VBE("Tools" > " 'MyProject' Properties..."), but I can't. A password is required here!

Does anyone have an idea that could help me get the access to the VBA code? 
Thank you so much!
I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Even if you find the password, you won't see any code in the frontend file (.accde). An .accde only contains compiled code. You need to locate the original development version of the frontend (.accdb).

Comment: Search for the origional accdb file. Otherwise, look into *Decompile Accde files*. I don't guaranty success...

Comment: Thank you guys! This actually helps me a lot!